# Visualizing the space of polynomials in finite fields for twin prime conjecture

Tags: number-theory

According to this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/big-question-about-primes-proved-in-small-number-systems-20190926/), we can think of prime polynomials of degree $n$ in a finite field as points in $F^{n+1}$ by just make the coefficients of the polynomials into a vector. In the example they gave, polynomial $2x+3$ with coefficients in finite field with 4 numbers lie on a sphere. But why are the space of polynomial form a sphere? Why not a plane?  How did they made the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

How do you define a unit sphere in a usual vector space? 
Well, if your vector $v = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ satisfies
$$ x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 = 1,$$ 
then we say that the vector $v$ lies in the unit sphere.

In this very same way, we write the polynomial of your example, $2x+3$ as $(2, 3) \in \mathbb{F}_4^2$, i.e. as a vector in the 2-dimensional vector space over the finite field with 4 elements. This vector in $\mathbb{F}_4^2$ indeed lies in the sphere since
$$ 2^2 + 3^2 = 13 \equiv 1 \mod{4}.$$

You can also consider planes (or hyperplanes) to be solutions of equations of the form
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i = k, $$
where $a_i,k$ are elements of your field of choice.